# What do I do when I run out of Pokeballs?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm halfway through level five but I have no pokeballs left. When I try to access a pokestop it says collect more pokestop modules. How do I do that? Also I would really prefer not to pay for pokeballs from the shop.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the error you get when you try to use a pokestop?

Comment: You're probably not spinning the Pokéstop.

Answer (score 3):

Pokeballs drop from PokeStops.  Make sure you're close enough to the stop before you try to spin for items.  Also make sure you don't click on the module button, that's how you set a lure on the PokeStop, not get items.